# Java Sockets: Request-response pattern with object streams

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

My objective is to implement a simple request-response pattern based on Java sockets
that is used to request an object from a server.

It should work like this:

1. The client sends a message to the server, which the server evaluates. Depending on what
   he received, a certain function is called. This part works.
2. The server writes the requested data into the ObjectOutputStream. This also works, at least 
   I didn't receive an error.
3. The client reads the data from the input stream until he receives a CLOSE message which makes the 
   program quit the while-loop. This does not work as it should.

Here are some critical code fragments:

```
// Client (Sending request) *** WORKS

objectOutputStream.writeInt(GET_OBJECT); 
objectOutputStream.flush();


// Server (After receipt of the message) *** WORKS
objectOutputStream.writeInt(object);
objectOutputStream.writeInt(CLOSE);



// Client (Reading the answer from the server) *** WRONG

while(true){
int i = objectInputStream.readInt(); 
if(i == CLOSE)
break;   
}
```

Comment: What is it returning for the value of `i`? if anything

Comment: Hello! It returned nothing. However, as Marko has noticed I have forgotten the flush() on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `flush` at the client side, and the message is received by the server;
2. you lack `flush` at the server side, and the message is not received by the client.

I notice a pattern in these two facts...

Comment: Thanks. It works now, but still very unreliable. Sometimes I receive the message from the server, sometimes not.

Comment: @user1812379 You need to flush every time you switch from writing to reading.